# Unable to Build ITK 5.* version on gcc / mingw 10 * - Pthread linking error/ windows10

Tags: gcc, pthreads, linker-errors, mingw-w64, itk

I am trying to compile itk from source, its with version 5.3.
On a windows 10 64 bit machine and with mingw-w64 version 10 installed i am using cmake(latest version) to build the itk source.

How ever during build i am getting a linker error of  " multiple definitions found  for most of the pthread functions" coming from another source file .

As i am directly building from source and not supposed change the source files any can tell me how to avoid that error ?

I have tried with **-fcommon**  **--allow-multiple-definition** linker options without any help.

Later found out that -fno-common was  introduced in latest gcc versions.

also is there any way to build ITK this version with any other compiler in windows 10 ?

I have tried with windows sdk latest but that does not give me the option to generate make files through cmake. And gives a strange error of Nmake file not found even though it is a default cmake generator of windows.

Please note :  **I am not interested in installing visual studio** . thats why cant get hold of msvc compilers.

47%] Building CXX object Modules/Core/Common/src/CMakeFiles/ITKCommon.dir/__/itkBuildInformation.cxx.obj
[ 47%] Linking CXX shared library ........\bin\libITKCommon-5.2.dll
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libpthread.a(libwinpthread_la-cond.o):cond.c:(.text+0x1100): multiple definition of `pthread_cond_timedwait'; ../../../../lib/libitkdouble-conversion-5.2.dll.a(d000091.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libpthread.a(libwinpthread_la-thread.o):thread.c:(.text+0x14a0): multiple definition of` pthread_once'; ../../../../lib/libitkdouble-conversion-5.2.dll.a(d000136.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libpthread.a(libwinpthread_la-thread.o):thread.c:(.text+0x1ac0): multiple definition of `pthread_self'; ../../../../lib/libitkdouble-conversion-5.2.dll.a(d000150.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libpthread.a(libwinpthread_la-mutex.o):mutex.c:(.text+0x80): multiple definition of` pthread_mutex_lock'; ../../../../lib/libitkdouble-conversion-5.2.dll.a(d000121.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libpthread.a(libwinpthread_la-mutex.o):mutex.c:(.text+0x3a0): multiple definition of `pthread_mutex_unlock'; ../../../../lib/libitkdouble-conversion-5.2.dll.a(d000124.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libpthread.a(libwinpthread_la-mutex.o):mutex.c:(.text+0x520): multiple definition of` pthread_mutex_init'; ../../../../lib/libitkdouble-conversion-5.2.dll.a(d000120.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libpthread.a(libwinpthread_la-mutex.o):mutex.c:(.text+0x570): multiple definition of `pthread_mutex_destroy'; ../../../../lib/libitkdouble-conversion-5.2.dll.a(d000119.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[5]: *** [Modules\Core\Common\src\CMakeFiles\ITKCommon.dir\build.make:1772: bin/libITKCommon-5.2.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:5302: Modules/Core/Common/src/CMakeFiles/ITKCommon.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[3]: *** [Makefile:155: all] Error 2
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\ITK.dir\build.make:85: ep/src/ITK-stamp/ITK-build] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1082: CMakeFiles/ITK.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:145: all] Error 2

Comment: You could install it directly form MSYS2 packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-itk or build it yourself github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-itk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MinGW is neither officially supported, [nor tested](https://open.cdash.org/index.php?project=Insight), so it is not surprising that it doesn't work. [Contributions](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) to add support are welcome.

Microsoft offers just the [command-line compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170), without needing Visual Studio. You might also have better luck with Clang for Windows than MinGW.

Comment: I have seen MS build tools earlier and tried to download as they claim to offer cl.exe which offer msvc environment . But not sure we can use build tools without purchasing license. Can we use build tool without purchasing?

Comment: I believe so: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2022/08/30/vsbt-licensing.aspx
Key quote: "VSBT can be used for compiling open source C++ dependencies from source without requiring a Visual Studio license, even for developers working for an enterprise on a commercial or closed-source project."

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am using VSBT and its working so far nicely, Even clang gave me hard time to compile few part of the source code with /MT /bigobj tag erros.